# How to minify all js and css in MEAN.JS for production environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meanjs

I have just developed a simple MEAN.JS application. MEAN.JS provides a command `grunt build` that helps me to minify the js and css files located at the following folders

```
css: [
    'public/modules/**/css/*.css'
],
js: [
    'public/config.js',
    'public/application.js',
    'public/modules/*/*.js',
    'public/modules/*/*[!tests]*/*.js'
]
```

but how about also minifies the third-party libraries, which is installed with `bower` and located in `public/lib/...`? All the needed js and css file paths are already inside the MEAN.JS environment config file.

Meanwhile, the minified js file `application.min.js` is really just "minified", not "uglified", the variables' names are still the same as the original and very long.

In short, has MEAN.JS already provided any ways or functions that can "uglified" all the js and css files including third-party libraries?

Comment: You'll need to integrate a javascript and css obfuscator into your build process to have the final minified file "uglified". There are many available. My suggestion is that you do a google search and look for the one that fits your build process better. https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Dv3HVcmSKqak8wfLqb_QDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=grunt+or+gulp+obfuscator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

To avoid errors when uglifying 3rd party files, only include non-minified 3rd party `.js` files in your `config/env/all.js` file.

---

Currently, your `grunt build` task uglifies your application javascript files but not your 3rd party javascript files. It does this via the `uglify` task in your `grunt.js` file.

```
uglify: {
 production: {
  options: {
    mangle: false
  },
  files: {
    'public/dist/application.min.js': 'public/dist/application.js'
  }
 }
},
```

If you want to uglify your 3rd party files I suggest taking the following steps:

**Add your vendor files to your `grunt.js` file and the `uglify` task:**

Change the configuration object (around line 170) to include your vendor files:

```
// A Task for loading the configuration object
grunt.task.registerTask('loadConfig', 'Task that loads the config into a grunt option.', function() {
    var init = require('./config/init')();
    var config = require('./config/config');

    // insert vendor files
    grunt.config.set("vendorJavaScriptFiles", config.assets.lib.js);
    // note: you can do the same for your css files
    grunt.config.set("vendorCSSFiles", config.assets.lib.css);

    grunt.config.set('applicationJavaScriptFiles', config.assets.js);
    grunt.config.set('applicationCSSFiles', config.assets.css);
});
```

Add your `vendorJavaScriptFiles` to your `uglify` task:

```
uglify: {
    production: {
        options: {
            mangle: false
        },
        files: {
            'public/dist/application.min.js': 'public/dist/application.js',
            'public/dist/vendor.min.js': '<%= vendorJavaScriptFiles %>'
        }
    }
}
```

**Change your `config/env/production.js` file to reflect your new `vendor.min` file:**

```
assets: {
    lib: {
        css: [
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
            // note you can follow a similar process for your css files
        ],
        js: 'public/dist/vendor.min.js'
    },
    css: 'public/dist/application.min.css',
    js: 'public/dist/application.min.js'
}
```

Now, when you run `grunt build` you should get both an `applicaiton.min.js` file and a `vendor.min.js` file in your `public/dist/` folder.

I separated them out for clarity, but you could combine them into one `application.min.js` file if you prefer.

Here is a much more detailed description of the process: https://blog.dylants.com/2014/11/19/bundling-production-assets-for-mean-js/

Hope this helps.